# Principles of Adding New Objects in Backend/Database and How Front End Business Logic Should Work with Response

Tags: front-end, backend

Apologies for the title, perhaps someone can suggest a better way to summarize my question.

Let's say I have a task/checklist application. On the front-end, I create a task. The eventual result is that the task exists in both the front-end and the database. I have these 2 approaches:

1. I create a task in the front end by first sending a request to the backend, then awaiting for the request result. If the result is 200, then I go ahead and create the task in the front end. Now I have both the task in the front end (displayed to the user) and in the backend (saved).
2. I create a task in the front end by first sending a request to the backed, then awaiting for the request result. The request then send back not only the status code, but the entire task object itself to the front end. I take the task object (deserialized) and display it to the user.

The considerations between the 2 are:

1. With `2` I don't need to update the logic of creating the task in 2 locations (in the front-end to create and display and in the back-end to create and store) and there could be inconsistencies between what the user sees and what is stored if incorrectly created/updated.
2. With `1` I have less network traffic. All the request needs to respond with is `200` and not the entire task object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just getting success status code is enough for you, it is OK. Use it and keep it simple.
But in real world, all your method can not work like that.

Assume that you create a new item. After create this item, you need to go further(maybe redirecting another page) with this item `Id`. How can you handle this `Id`? In this case, just **200 status code** is not enough for you. If you need any information like `Id`, then you can read data and turn it back as response. It can be entire data or part of them.

Considering **Network Traffic** and another resources is good. Try not to turn back unused data. If you need to read huge data, then parse it properly and send more than one request to the server. You just need to balance **User Waiting Response Time** and **Network Traffic** in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! One clarification: if I don't need to "go further" is it still valuable to send back the entire object as the response? Otherwise, I would need to maintain 2 locations where I create the object; backend and frontend.

Comment: I don't think so or I can't imagine your case. Assume that you create a _thing_ and you don't need to go further. So, you can turn your _things_ list page and let user do what he/she wants. If he/she want to see object details, then you can request to the server to get object details. Why are you storing object on front-end if you don't need to use it(no need to going further)

Comment: Ah! "don't need to go further" as in I don't necessarily need the information from the response. This may be bad practice on my part, but I'm generating `Id` on the front end, and sending that to the backend, so I wouldn't need that info from the response. The _thing_ is then shown to the user, so I would need to store it on the front-end as well. Essentially, this case I would need to create the _thing_ in 2 places if I don't get the _thing_ from the response!

Comment: _I'm generating Id on the front end_ is not bad practice. It is dangerous. How do you manage each object has different `Id`?

Comment: My _id_s are UUIDs randomly generated and are thus highly probable to be unique. They are sent to the backend. Sure someone could make a non-client API call with a conflicting UUID, but the backend will return a non-200 status code. I could definitely be naive, but thoughts on why that could be dangerous?

Comment: If you don't manage Id, it is dangerous. If you manage it from front-end layer it is bad practice because you strict your project with one front-end. If you need to add another front-end layer in the future, you can not serve it directly. You need to copy your logic. It also against DRY.

Comment: Got it. That makes perfect sense. I would be sure to manage my Ids in the backend. And with that, that answers my original question. Thank you!